# Laravel Jetstream + Socialite + 2FA

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-socialite

We started a new project with Laravel Jetstream (Inertia / vuejs) and implemented Laravel Socialite.

When a new user register, login, enable 2FA and re-login the 2FA works fine, but when a user login with Socialite (Microsoft), enable 2FA and re-login the user doesn’t get the 2FA form, but go straight to the dashboard.

How can we use fortify to handle the 2fa processes for socialite users?